# Displaying Bluetooth Serial Data

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I am new to Android development and have been working with Bluetooth communication on my Tablet running 4.2.2. I am looking to receive data sent from a Bluetooth module to my Tablet.  I have a good understanding of how to set up Bluetooth sockets via the Android website, however I need help in receiving the incoming serial data.  Using the code below, I am able to find the module, open a socket connection and connect to it (as indicated by a green light on the module), however I need help in displaying the transmitted data on the UI via a TextView.  The module is sending 2 bytes of data every second at 9600 baud.  It is my understanding that run() reads in the 2 bytes of data and stores it in the buffer.  Then these bytes get passed to the handler which display it on the screen via "case MESSAGE_READ;".  Could someone please let me know what I am doing incorrectly?

```
package com.example.bluetoothtest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

TextView mTextView;
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
ListView listView;
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray;
ArrayList<String> pairedDevices;
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;
public static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
protected static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;
IntentFilter filter;
BroadcastReceiver receiver;
String tag = "debugging";
Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(tag, "in handler");
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what){
        case SUCCESS_CONNECT:

            ConnectedThread connectedThread = new     ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECT", 0).show();
            String s = "successfully connected";
            connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
            Log.i(tag, "connected");
            break;
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            String str = (String)msg.obj;
            mTextView.setText(str); 
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg); 
        }
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtData);
    init();
    if(btAdapter==null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No bluetooth detected", 0).show();
        finish();
    }
    else{
        if(!btAdapter.isEnabled()){
            turnOnBT();
        }

        getPairedDevices();
        startDiscovery();
    }


}
private void startDiscovery() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    btAdapter.startDiscovery();

}
private void turnOnBT() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent =new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
private void getPairedDevices() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    devicesArray = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(devicesArray.size()>0){
        for(BluetoothDevice device:devicesArray){
            pairedDevices.add(device.getName());

        }
    }
}
private void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    listAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,0);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    pairedDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice device =     intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                devices.add(device);
                String s = "";
                for(int a = 0; a < pairedDevices.size(); a++){
                       if(device.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))){
                        //append 
                        s = "(Paired)";
                        break;
                    }
                }

                listAdapter.add(device.getName()+" "+s+" "+"\n"+device.getAddress());
            }

            else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){

            }
            else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){

            }

            else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
                if(btAdapter.getState() == btAdapter.STATE_OFF){
                    turnOnBT();
                }
            }

        }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
     filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
     filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
     filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth must be enabled to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(btAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        if(listAdapter.getItem(arg2).contains("Paired")){

            BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(arg2);
            ConnectThread connect = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
            connect.start();
            Log.i(tag, "in click listener");
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "device is not paired", 0).show();
        }
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
            // because mmSocket is final
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;
            Log.i(tag, "construct");
            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                Log.i(tag, "get socket failed");

            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.i(tag, "connect - run");
            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
                Log.i(tag, "connect - succeeded");
            } catch (IOException connectException) {    Log.i(tag, "connect failed");
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                return;
            }

            // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)

            mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
        }

        /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            Log.i(tag, "socket connect success");
            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                Log.i(tag, "socket success");
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {  
            Log.i(tag, "run success");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2];
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read() 

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs 
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream 
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    Log.i(tag, "buffer read OK");
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity 
                    String str = new String(buffer); 
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, str).sendToTarget();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i(tag, "buffer read failed");
                    System.out.print("read error"); 
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the result differ from what you expect?  What is the nature of the data?  Does it already consist of printable character codes?  Or is it a number you will have to convert to a textual representation for display?

Comment: @ChrisStratton the UI is not displaying anything. My Bluetooth is transmitting the 2 byte ADC result.  Specifically, it is sending 03 FF (1023 in decimal). I have confirmed this by receiving 03 FF on a hyperterminal on my computer. I will deal with formatting once I can get the UI to displaying something.  Is there anything in particular about my code that would cause it not to work?  If this looks OK, I can eliminate this from the problem and I can post the rest of the code.

Comment: Perhaps there's a problem with your Handler.  You could try logging the received characters immediately after obtaining them.  Also, the way you have it written if it ever fails it looks like it may give up for good, and never (reconnect and?) start trying again.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I think perhaps there might be something else going on, so I posted the complete code.  If there was an error reading in the bytes, I should have received a "read error" from the catch.  I am thinking that run() is never being executed but I am not sure where the error in the code is.

Comment: Rather than make assumptions, just put in logging to check that the various pieces are working, then actually check the logs.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks. I have implemented debugging by logging in LogCat and found out that the run() thread in 'private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {' which contains the read in code is not executing. Everything prior to run() is executing as it should, i.e. 'tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();' is executing. I am also simultaneously running a thread in the 'private class ConnectThread extends Thread {' which is used to connect the socket, and this is OK. Why is this part of the code not running?

Comment: Try making your log message the absolute first thing to happen in the run() method.  Also put a log message at the end of the constructor.  You sure there aren't any exceptions in logcat?

Comment: I have done that and the log message does not appear in logcat.  I added Log.i(tag, "run success"); just under public void run() {.  I updated the full code.

Comment: You have some sort of fault, but you cannot see it as your Exception handlers silently swallow the Exceptions.  Each one needs an e.printStackTrace() so you can see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

case SUCCESS_CONNECT:

```
    ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECT", 0).show();
    String s = "successfully connected";
    connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
    Log.i(tag, "connected");
    connectedThread.run();

    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should call `connectedThread.start()`, NOT `connectedThread.run()`. The `start()` method causes `connectedThread` to do its `run()` method on a separate thread, If you directly call `run()`, is suggested above, then only that `run()` method (which is usally an infinite loop, will block all other code, including the UI thread.